# How does oyster card work with child fare (example)

Tags: london, children, tfl, oyster-card

This question is related to...

[Oyster Card - how does it actually work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/oyster-card-how-does-it-actually-work)

But it's not the same.

So basically I'm traveling to London as a tourist and plan to stay for 1 day seeing the sights, etc. - 2 adults and 2 children, one aged 5 and the other 13.

The way I understand the Oyster card is, I get to London. I plan to park in North Ealing car park which is in zone 3. Now I need an Oyster card for each of us to travel.

So I buy 2 for the adults, this will cost me £10 and I'll put on £7.70 credit for each of us (the "Cap" is £7.70 for zone 3.) for a total (so far) of £25.40

I'll also need one for the older child. The Cap for an 11-15 year old is £3.85. Now the website states that he will need a "Oyster Zip Photo" card or something? Can this be bought at the station just like the adult ones? Does it also have the £5 refundable deposit? And if not, do I need a full (adult) price Oyster card for him too, so another £5 + £7.70 credit?

Then I have another child aged 5. From my understanding, she can travel for free because she's accompanied by an adult who is using a "Pay as you go" Oyster card?

Then to get my refund, can I just go into the same station where I bought them and hand them back and get my £15 back?

Comment: Just a bit of useful info in case anyone is in a similar situation: We were advised by a station staff member that because you need 48 hours before the deposit can be refunded (and we weren't staying that long), the best course of action would be: the 13 year old get a child travel card for £6.10. Then the two adults would simply use our contactless debit cards to tap in and out at the turn-styles and it would still cost £7.70 each for the day. Doesn't answer my specific question but ended up working out well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is explained pretty clearly at https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/travel-for-under-18s/zip-oyster-photocards#on-this-page-1.  You would have to apply for an Oyster Zip Photocard online, allow a week or more for delivery, and there is a £15 administration fee which is not refundable.  So for a one-day trip, it is probably better just to buy an ordinary adult Oyster card for the older child, and pay the adult fares.

Your younger child can travel for free:

> Your child doesn't need a 5-10 Zip Oyster photocard: [...]
>
> - If you accompany your child on Tube, DLR, London Overground, TfL Rail and some National Rail services. Check this map to
>     see the services on which they can do this.

You can return the cards and get the deposits refunded at any ticket machine, as well as any remaining pay-as-you-go credit, up to £10 per card,  See https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/replacements-and-refunds/oyster-refunds-and-replacements

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question, but I didn't see anything about the administration fee or that you have to apply several weeks in advance in the link you provided.

Comment: @colmde: Scroll down to where it says "Find out how to apply if you:" and expand the appropriate box.  The fee is actually £15 for 11-15 year olds (I was reading the wrong section).  In the best case you can get it by post, which they say takes one week plus mailing time.